# Do browser notifications threaten privacy/anonymity when using a VPN?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, vpn, anonymity

These:

[image]

Do they threaten privacy/anonymity on a VPN?

In this particular case, I'm using Opera VPN, which I thought might bear mentioning because it's a browser-based VPN, but I am asking about regular VPNs too.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Safe for/from what?

Comment: @schroeder when someone says "safe" on this site, they obviously mean that no identifying information is revealed. Being cutesy over the use of the word "safe" is not useful.

Comment: No, that's not obvious at all or an assumption one can make. As a mod here for years, I can point to numerous examples where, when I have asked this question, I have received a spectrum of answers.

Comment: Security traditionally covers the CIA triad, and people value certain subsets within that triad.

Comment: As you can see from the provided answer, a user took "safe" to mean "safe from effects of misuse", which is a different use case.

Comment: @schroeder it's obvious you'd rather be cute about semantics than supply a useful answer.

Comment: ... Except the answer I provided ... Just because something is obvious to *you* does not make it inherently obvious. That's what clarifying questions are for...

Answer (score 1):

The security of notifications is about the same as popups. This means that they can be useful but they can also be misused to be annoying and they can be misused to trick the user, i.e. for phishing. This risk does not change in any way if a VPN is used.

This means, if you did not like it before or found it too risky you should keep it off by default also when using a VPN. This also means that you can allow notifications on selected sites where they provide added value for you no matter if you use a VPN or not.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are just code run on the browser sent by the server. You are already running the site's code in your browser when you initially visit the site.

So, enabling notifications does not expose your identifying information any more than visiting the site initially does.

***As a side note***, a VPN has no bearing on the blocking of identifying information. That's not what a VPN is for. VPNs do not make you anonymous to the site. Their purpose is to protect the traffic between your device/browser and the site or an intermediary point. Some VPNs have the side effect of acting as a *proxy*, which can obscure where your device is if the site looks at the IP alone. But there are multiple ways of identifying the device and its location even if a VPN is used.

If you were thinking that a VPN would protect you from that, then you are using the wrong protection mechanism.